# Sending email using smtplib without logging in

Tags: python, smtplib

I have the below code which logs into a test gmail account and sends an email.

```
msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'Testing Attachments'
msg['From'] = "testing@gmail.com"
msg['To'] = "testing@gmail.com"
msg.set_content("Document attached...")

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465) as smtp:

    smtp.login("testing@gmail.com", "password")
    smtp.send_message(msg)
```

When moving my code into production, I will be using an internal SMTP server rather than Gmail. Will I still be required to login or could I run the below code successfully?

```
msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'Testing Attachments'
msg['From'] = "testing@internalsmtp.com"
msg['To'] = "testrecipients@internalsmtp.com"
msg.set_content("Document attached...")

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.internal.com", 465) as smtp:

    smtp.send_message(msg)
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: It depends entirely on how the server is configured.

Comment: I think it does. Thank you

Comment: That's interesting Chris, thanks. Edit: This has been done before by a colleague using VB. He wasn't required to create a new email account yet sends emails from his script using an email address he fabricated. So the server must allow it